# Using UIPageControl to display mutliple UICollectionViews

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton, uipagecontrol

-- I'm relatively new to iOS Development --

I'm currently working on an application for a restaurant.
A functionality of the application is that the staff will be able to pick what table the customers are sitting at, before handing the device to them.

I'm currently trying to do this by listing each table as a button, using a Collection View.

The tables are split up in to two groups: Inside and Outside.

My goal is to separate 'Inside' tables and 'Outside' tables using a page control.

Here's what I have so far:

[Page 1: #1 to #24 resembles the Inside Tables, whilst the rest resemble the Outside Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpo8U.png)

[Page 2: Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T49wH.png)

Class 1: CollectionViewCell

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableButton: UIButton!
}
```

Class 2: TableNumSelection

```
class TableNumSelection: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var typeLabel: UILabel!

let types = ["Inside", "Outside"]

let tables = [["#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5", "#6", "#7", "#8", "#9", "#10", "#11", "#12", "#13", "#14", "#15", "#16", "#17", "#18", "#19", "#20", "#21", "#22", "#23", "#24"], ["#501", "#502", "#503", "#504", "#505", "#506", "#507", "#508", "#509", "#510", "#511", "#512", "#513", "#514", "#515", "#516", "#517", "#518", "#519", "#520", "#521", "#522", "#523", "#524", "#525", "#526", "#527", "#528", "#529", "#530", "#531"]]

var frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 2

    for i in 0..<tables.count {
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size

        typeLabel.text = types[i]

        let numberOfItems = collectionView(collectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: i)
        print(numberOfItems)
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(tables.count)), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.delegate = self
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return tables[0].count
    }
    else {
        return tables[1].count
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    print(indexPath)
    let section = indexPath.section

    if section == 0 {
        cell.tableButton.setTitle(tables[0][indexPath.item], for: UIControl.State.normal)
        cell.tableButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        return cell
    } else {
        cell.tableButton.setTitle(tables[1][indexPath.item], for: UIControl.State.normal)
        cell.tableButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.item)
}
```

I have no problems with the swipe and page-change functionality as this works fine, however:

I've tried splitting the tables into two sections, though I don't have any idea on how I could display each section on a separate page (i.e section 0 on Page 1 and section 1 on Page 2).

Do I need to create two Collection Views? Or can I simply separate by section as I've *rather unsuccessfully* attempted?

[The Scene hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m20kU.png)

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure: your collection view is a subview of a scrollview?

Comment: This is correct, I've attached an image showing the hierarchy of the Scene.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice. If you want to stick with your current view hierarchy, then you'll need to create separate collection view for each page (using this solution your `UIPageControl` will be relative to your outermost scroll view. 
An alternative (an better imo) solution would be to use a single `UICollectionView` with multiple sections. Each sections will be the size the devices's screen. If you don't mind doing it programmatically then you'll find this tutorial helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5yjOMLBfSc